# OpenLayers type of Overlays supported

Tags: openlayers

I'm working on a GIS OpenLayer solution. I'm trying to find what overlay type OpenLayers supports but alas I cannot?

Where can I find what Overlay types OpenLayers supports or what they are?

Answer (score 0):

From [OpenLayers Library - Overlays](http://docs.openlayers.org/library/overlays.html)

> **Overlay Basics** 
>   There are two different types of feature rendering in
>   OpenLayers. One type is the OpenLayers Vector Overlays support, which
>   uses vector drawing capabilities in the browser (SVG, VML, or Canvas)
>   to display data. The other type is the OpenLayers Marker Overlays
>   support. This type of layer displays HTML image objects inside the
>   DOM.
>
> In general, the Vector layer provides more capabilities, with the
>   ability to draw lines, polygons, and more. The Vector-based Layers are
>   better maintained, and are the place where most new OpenLayers
>   development is taking place. There is more support for various styling
>   options, and more configurability over layer behavior and interactions
>   with remote servers.
>
> However, the Markers layer is maintained for backwards compatibility,
>   because there are some things you can not do with vectors as they are
>   currently implemented, and they provide a different type of interface
>   for event registration.

A number of OverLay layers inherit from either OpenLayers.Layer.Marker or OpenLayers.Layer.Vector such as [OpenLayers.Layer.PointTrack](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/PointTrack-js.html) and [PointGrid](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/PointGrid-js.html) or [OpenLayers.Layer.GeoRSS](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/GeoRSS-js.html).  Full details can be found in [the documentation](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Layer-js.html) or you could Fork [OpenLayers on GitHub](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers) and have a look at the code yourself.

Answer (score -1):

OpenLayers can display lots of different types of layers as overlay. Check out Layer section in [documentation](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.11/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers-js.html) to get the idea of what it's capable.